# Oracle dump file table data extraction to file (original exp format)

Tags: oracle, etl, exp, imp

I have Oracle dump files created with original exp (not expdp) (EXPORT:V10.02.01, Oracle 10g). They contain only table data for four tables.

1) I want to extract the table data into files (flat/fixed-width, CVS, or other text file) without importing them into another Oracle DB. [preferred]

2) Alternatively, I need a solution that can import them into an ordinary user (not SYSDBA) so that I can use other tools to extract the data.

My databases are 11g, but I can find 10g databases if needed. I have TOAD for Oracle Xpert 11.6.1.6 as my disposal. I am a moderately experieinced Oracle programmer, but I haven't worked with EXP/IMP before.

*(The information below has been obscured to protect the data.)*

Here's how the dump files were created:

```
exp FILE=data.dmp \
LOG=data.log \
TABLES=USER1.TABLE1,USER1.TABLE2,USER1.TABLE3,USER1.TABLE4 \
INDEXES=N TRIGGERS=N CONSTRAINTS=N GRANTS=N
```

Here's the log:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
Export done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR character set
Note: grants on tables/views/sequences/roles will not be exported
Note: indexes on tables will not be exported
Note: constraints on tables will not be exported

About to export specified tables via Conventional Path ...
Current user changed to USER1
. . exporting table                      TABLE1        271 rows exported
. . exporting table                      TABLE2     272088 rows exported
. . exporting table                      TABLE3       2770 rows exported
. . exporting table                      TABLE4      21041 rows exported
Export terminated successfully without warnings.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's stopping you importing them using `imp`?

Comment: I have the dump files. I need the data. But I don't need it in the database and these are privileged commands that I'd rather avoid. I just want at the table data in a flat file. That said, I am working with imp and a server to get the data and export it. I am leaving the question open for a bit to see if anyone else has tried this.

Comment: You said that you'd be okay importing them and exporting them in a flag-file format though. What's stopping you from using `imp` to do so? You're not going to be able to get them in a flat file unless you get them into a database somehow as a dmp file is a binary, proprietary, Oracle format.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:
TOAD version 9.7.2 will read a "dmp" file generated by EXP.

Select DATABASE -> EXPORT -> EXPORT FILE BROWSER from the menus.

You need to have the DBA utilities for TOAD installed.  There is no real guarantee that the file is parsed
correctly, but the data will show up in TOAD in the schema browser.

**NOTE**: The only other known utility that will a dmp file generated by the **exp** utility is the `imp`utility.  You **cannot** read the dump file yourself.  If you do, you run the risk of parsing the file incorrectly.

If you already have the data in an ORACLE table:

To extract the table data into a file, create a shell script that calls SQL*PLUS and causes SQL*PLUS to spool the table data to a file.  You need one script per table.

```
#!/bin/sh
#NOTE: The path to sqlplus will vary on your system,
#      but it is generally $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus.
#YOU NEED TO UNCOMMENT THESE LINES AND SET APPROPRIATELY.
#export ORACLE_SID=YOUR_SID
#export ORACLE_HOME=PATH_TO_YOUR_ORACLE_HOME
#export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
sqlplus -s user/pwd@db << EOF
set pagesize 0
set linesize 0
set linesize 255
set heading off
set echo off
SPOOL TABLE1_DATA.txt
REM FOR EACH COLUMN IN TABLE1, SET THE FORMAT
COL FIELD_ID   format 999,999,999
COL FIELD_DATA format a99
select FIELD_ID,FIELD_DATA from TABLE1;
SPOOL OFF
EOF
```

Make sure you set the line size of each line and set the format of each column.  See FIELD_ID above for a number format column and FIELD_DATA for a character column.
NOTE: You need to remove the "N rows selected" from the end of the file.

(You can still import the file you created into another schema using the `imp`utility.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this was not what I needed. I know how to export data from an Oracle database. My data is in dump files created by exp (not expdp), not in Oracle. I want to extract the data without having to import it into Oracle.

Comment: You can still use the above SQL script to save the table data in a text file and then import the data into EXCEL or another application.  You can only use the dump files for importing.  You cannot manually read a dump file with any other application than imp.

Comment: It wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but it is an answer. The answer is "No".However, I'm still holding out hope that in all the years of Oracle development, someone out there has faced this problem, and created a solution.

Comment: If your data is only in dump files, you have to import it into a database first.  Anyone that can externally read the dump files would have to have access to proprietary ORACLE code.  Let me see if there is an official ORACLE utility to read these files.  However, I have never seen this before.